# React.js, print something after all getDownloadURL functions completes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to get all the URL from Firebase.I need to print something after all the `getDownloadURL` completes. I have tried to add `.then(function()){}`after the `storageRef.listAll()`, however it does not work. Can someone help me? Thank you so much!

```
  getAllURL = product => {

       // Get all the images from the firebase  
        var storage = firebase.storage();
        var that = this;
        const storageRef =  storage.ref(`image/${product}`)

        storageRef.listAll().then(function(result) { 
          result.items.forEach(function(imageRef) {
                imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {    

                  let a = 'a'            
                  that.state.temp3.push(a)
                  console.log("789")

                }).catch(function(error) {});

                console.log("123")
         })
          console.log("456")
       })            
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I declared a variable called `promises` and assigned all of the promises to it. After that, I used `Promise.all` to wait for all of the promises to resolve.

```
getAllURL = product => {
  // Get all the images from the firebase
  var storage = firebase.storage();
  var that = this;
  const storageRef = storage.ref(`image/${product}`);

  storageRef.listAll().then(function(result) {
    const promises = result.items.map(function(imageRef) {
      return imageRef
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(function(url) {
          let a = "a";
          that.state.temp3.push(a);
          console.log("789");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {});
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((results) => console.log('Promises resolved', results))
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!